# JSF creates wrong URL to jsf.js

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I try to learn JSF. When using commandLink, JSF render it to HTML with a Javascript-Code:

#### Source:

```
<p><h:form><a jsfc="h:commandLink" action="#{user.logout}">Logout</a></h:form></p>
```

#### Rendered:

```
<p>
  <form id="j_idt15" name="j_idt15" method="post" action="/smsalert/auth/welcome.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="j_idt15" value="j_idt15" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/*/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces">     </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt15'),{'j_idt15:j_idt16':'j_idt15:j_idt16'},'');return false">Log Out</a><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-4859709923894071294:-3975844660345501662" autocomplete="off" />
  </form>
</p>
```

The problem is the generated URL to jsf.js (/*/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js...). I tried to google the problem but didn't found much helpful.. How can I solve this Problem?

The method that is invoked by clicking on Logout:

```
public String logout() {
  logged = false;
  return "index";
}
```

EDITED:

I got it! The error was my web.xml. I had

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I replaced it with

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

it works!

Comment: Which Mojarra version?

Comment: post your xhtml header + meta!, do you use a doc base ? and how do you defined the faces servlet pattern in your web.xml?

Comment: Instead editing your question, you should post an answer and accept it after two days.